# Does AudioKit 4+ support AKFrequencyTracker with Objective C?

Tags: audiokit

I'm trying to incorporate AudioKit 4.0.3 (latest) into an existing iOS ViewController that's written in Objective C. I am having trouble initializing and using the AKFrequencyTracker class, even though other classes work fine (e.g. AKOscillator and AKMicrophone).

I added the following code to the ViewController viewDidLoad method in the Objective C example that came with it:

```
AKMicrophone *mic;
mic = [[AKMicrophone alloc] init];

AKFrequencyTracker *tracker;
tracker = [[AKFrequencyTracker alloc] init:mic hopSize:512.0 peakCount:20.0];
```

But I see an "No visible @interface for 'AKFrequencyTracker'" error in Xcode next to the last line.

It doesn't appear there are any init methods for AKFrequencyTracker. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to a change with Swift 4 we need to explicitly add @objc to the init methods and forgot to do so with AKFrequencyTracker. I just fixed it in this commit: 
https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/commit/e9328d4aa8d76d0cae31eeb33b232abebd571d6e

Comment: Wow, what service! Thanks for your help.

Comment: By the way, AKBooster has the same issue. Thanks again. @Aurelius

Comment: Pretty sure that was fixed right after the frequency tracker https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/commit/d31ed73157d8959166175298774457cbfd3ba3df